# Difference between passing "*" and '*' arguments to split

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logic

I am working on spark - scala and find out that in scala. the splitting is different than python. As an example:

My function:

```
for (line <- lines) {
  var fields = line.split("|")
  if(fields.length > 1){
    movieNames += (fields(0).toInt -> fields(1))
  }
```

gives me an ERROR but when I change it to ...

```
for (line <- lines) {
  var fields = line.split('|')
  if(fields.length > 1){
    movieNames += (fields(0).toInt -> fields(1))
  }
```

then, It will solve so, what is the **difference between " | " and  ' | ' at logic level**.

Answer (score 6):

The [**docs**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) are your friend.

`line.split("|")` calls the `split` version that receives a **String**, such version treats that **String** as a *regex*.
And `|` is not a valid *regex*.

Whereas `line.split('|')` calls the `split` version that receives a **Char**, such version just split the line every time it finds that character.